# Logic behind instagram's "heart-ing" posts smooth api call

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to learn flutter by recreating a similar app like **instagram**.
I'm brainstorming and trying to think of the logic behind the *smooth scrolling of posts while liking each post.*

In my code, whenever I try to like a post, It freezes for a second because of the `API` for liking a post is being called.

is there some tricks to this? I hope you can help me. TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you shouldn't wait for the server response to confirm liking a post. instantly mark it as liked (show the liking animation) then send the like and don't `await` it. next time the user loads the post, if the like action was successful it loads with a red heart else it either is never viewed before or last time the user liked it, it was not successful.

you either do that, or you spin up another isolate just to do the API call in the background which is probably unnecessary because API calls are not that computationally expensive.

Comment: I'll try to remove the `await` thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: IT DID THE TRICK!! you're a hero dude. thanks a lot!